# Bootstrap nav-pills not changing content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to build a navbar that changes my content depending on which nav pill was clicked. **IDK** why it doens't change the content in my ***div.tab-content***...

This is a code example:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="navigation" role="navigation">
      <!-- pills content -->
      <ul  class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="detail_tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <a
                  class="nav-link active"
                  id="pill1" 
                  data-mdb-toggle="pill"
                  href="#content1"
                  role="tab"
                  aria-controls="content1"
                  aria-selected="true"                        
              >pill1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <a
                  class="nav-link"
                  id="pill2" 
                  data-mdb-toggle="pill"
                  href="#content2"
                  role="tab"
                  aria-controls="content2"
                  aria-selected="false"                        
              >pill2</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- pills nav -->


      <!-- pills content -->
      <div class="tab-content clearfix" id="tablist-content">
          <div
              class="tab-pane fade show active"
              id="content1"
              role="tabpanel"
              aria-labelledby="pill1"
          >
              content1
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="content2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pill2">
              content2
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- pills content -->
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Why does it not work? Did I forgot anything?

Comment: You don't seem to have followed the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior) properly. What is `data-mdb-toggle`?

Comment: From @BrunoPrates (not enough rep. to comment): *Change data-mdb-toogle to data-bs-toogle*

Answer (score 0):

Change `data-mdb-toogle` to `data-bs-toogle`.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).